# Не могу поставить React сайт на хостинг

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

Я разрабатываю сайт на React при установке на хостинг в документации пишет что нужно добавить директиву `-MultiViews` в файл `.htaccess`, но из за неё падает 500 ошибка, а без этой директивы сайт не хочет работать (не воспринимает параметры в `URL`) что делать подскажите пожалуйста? Поддержка хостинга мне сказала что `-MultiViews` добавлять нельзя, из-за него падает 500 ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом же файле `.htaccess` необходимо убрать строки:

```
# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

и параметры в URL должны начать восприниматься нормально, и ссылки заработают нормально. Полезная ссылка: [What is Options +FollowSymLinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30911880/5275890)

Comment: Изначально это не помогло, но как оказалось далее моя проблема была в браузере "Opera" почему то он выдавал ошибку хотя другие браузеры нет (Chrome, Mozilla, Edge). И в итоге  в этих браузерах всё заработало.